# Find employees employed at the same position as 'someone'

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get data about employees who employed at the same position as 'Someone'.

```
var context = new Models.DBService();

var job = from emp in context.EMPs
          where emp.ENAME.Equals("BLAKE")
          select emp.JOB;

var result = from emp in context.EMPs
             where emp.JOB.Equals(job)
             select emp;
```

What is actually happening is that from the first query I'm getting the length of the job on which 'BLAKE' is employed instead of the name of the job. Here is my exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration
>   types and entity types are supported.'

Comment: What is the type of `emp.ENAME`?

Comment: is job a string or is job something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually get the "job" from the DB you need to materialize the query by using something like `Single()`, assuming that you know that your query will have exactly one result.

```
var job = (from emp in context.EMPs
          where emp.ENAME.Equals("BLAKE")
          select emp.JOB).Single();
```

Alternatively you can use the `job` query in the other query with `Contains`.

```
var result = from emp in context.EMPs
             where job.Contains(emp.JOB)
             select emp;
```

And note that at this point `result` is just a query that you'll have to materialize to get the employees with a `ToList` or by iterating it in a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

1º First you get the job from where you want

2º You query again comparing the emp.Job to the string that came on the first query

3º And it's Finished

```
var job = (from emp in context.EMPs
              where emp.ENAME.ToLower() == ("BLAKE").ToLower()
              select emp.JOB).FirstOrDefault();

 var result = from emp in context.EMPs
               where emp.JOB == job
              select emp).FirstOrDefault();
```